# Where in the world is this?

Tags: where-on-earth

[image: Where is this]

This picture is on my windows 10. I would like to know where it is.

thank you

Comment: Browsing one of the sites listed in the duplicate gives: https://spotlight.it-notes.ru/images/8318ae05ba88ffc7cd6b9c6544882539 "Sunset aerial view from Reinebringen ridge on mountains and village of Reine in Lofoten islands, Norway"

Answer (score 1):

And a right click on the image (if your browser is Google Chrome), selecting **Search Google for image** returns [Reine, Norway:](https://www.switchbacktravel.com/norway/lofoten-islands/reine)

> This tiny and incredibly picturesque fishing village is one of best places to stay as you explore the Lofoten Islands.